# How to stream tweets of one user using "follow"

Tags: node.js, twitter, node-twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter api to listen for tweets from one user (`1234`)

```
twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: 1234 }, (stream) => {
    stream.on('data', tweet => {
      console.log('tweet', tweet)
    })

    stream.on('error', error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  })
```

This is a node wrapper for Twitter, [node-twitter](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter) or just 'twitter' on npm.

The developer documentation for this feature is here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

My issue is the `console.log('tweet', tweet)` line never fires, even when I tweet or reply. However, if I use `{ filter: 'MyKeywordHere' }` as the second parameter, it does fire. So why can't I follow my account activity?

Comment: your code works fine. I can't replicate the issue. 1-  possible reasons maken sure twitter id is valid Id 2- share other part of your code

Answer (score 4):

The follow value must be a string

```
{ follow: 1234 }
```

becomes:

```
{ follow: '1234' }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but sadly it makes no difference that I can tell.

Comment: yeah, that's the answer; you must be using the wrong user ID. Get the user ID from http://mytwitterid.com/

Answer (score 2):

This code works!
Package: [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit)

```
var Twit = require('twit')


var TW = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '#####',
  consumer_secret: '#####',
  access_token: '#####-#####',
  access_token_secret: '#####',
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000, // optional, HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
});

var TWId = '#####'; // string

var stream = TW.stream('statuses/filter', {
  follow: TWId
});

console.log('Waiting for tweets, Id:  ' + TWId);

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
});
```

This code also works!
Package: [twitter](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter)

```
var Twit = require('twitter')


var TW = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '#####',
  consumer_secret: '#####',
  access_token_key: '#####-#####',
  access_token_secret: '#####',
});

var TWId = '#####'; // string

var stream = TW.stream('statuses/filter', {
  follow: TWId
});

console.log('Waiting for tweets, Id:  ' + TWId);

stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
});

stream.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Still nothing, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because there is no user with 1234 as `user_id`.

> My issue is the console.log('tweet', tweet) line never fires, even
>   when I tweet or reply.

Make sure that you are trying with your own `user_id` as `follow` parameter.